# Mechanisms Underlying Homophily: Social Influence

Tags: graph-theory

I am preparing for the lecture next week and I found a problem of finding the number of foci.

Projected graph satisfies: an edge will be formed if and only if two individuals participate the same social activities (foci).

[Here is a picture of a network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q28e4.png)

From the above graph, what is the minimum number of social activities (foci) in that affiliation network? Could you please include the explanation.

[Similar question from textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz3LU.png)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, $n$ individuals $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ participate in the same foci if and only if the subgraph induced by $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ is complete. So all triangles give one foci each, and there is no other foci in that network. However I don't understand why the question is asking for a minimal number of foci? Minimal with respect to which property?

Comment: @RandyMarsh Actually it is a question from my tutorial exercise. I thought there are 2 foci (node E, F) but I saw a similar question from the textbook (updated in my question above). It states that there are at least four foci in the same graph. I am skeptical about the minimum number in the graph, so I try to get help.

Comment: Can you please define what the vertices (nodes) and what the edges of the graph are? Your definition of what is an edge implies that the nodes are individuals, but you say in the above comment that node E and F are 2 foci. By my understanding, the nodes are individuals and for example ABE are in the same foci because there is an edge between any two individuals, but ABCE are not in the same foci because there is no edge BC.

Comment: Does an edge mean that two individuals participate in **all** the same activities, or does it mean that there is at least **one** activity that both participate in?

Comment: @bof An edge will be formed if and only if two individuals participate in the same social activities (foci). As long as a node participate in an activity (no matter how many activities they join), an edge will be formed.

Comment: @RandyMarsh I think the question is asking to define whether that node is a focus or a person. I guess (cause I haven't learned the lecture yet) node E is a focus cause node A, B are connected to node E. Node F is also a focus because node B, D are connected to F. That's why I guess there are two foci. But from my textbook, it is the same graph from the exercise stated that there are at least four foci. I want to know whether the textbook and exercise are talking about the same thing. I am so confused too.

Comment: It's unlikely that nodes represent two different types of information (people and foci) at the same time. Going by the textbook question, nodes represent people. There is no reason why E should be a focus just because A and B connect to it. B and E connect to A but you don't call A a focus.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Maybe I misunderstand the question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Two people $A$ and $B$ share at least one focus if there is an edge $AB$.

Three people $A$, $B$ and $C$ share at least one focus if there are edges $AB$, $AC$ and $BC$, that is if $A$, $B$ and $C$ form a triangle.

By looking just at the edges, $10$ distinct foci are needed to cover all people. But $AB$, $AC$ and $BC$ can all have the same focus because they form a triangle, so the minimal number of foci needed to cover $A$, $B$ and $C$ is $1$.

Similarly, we don't need 3 foci for each of $ACE$, $BDF$ or $CDF$, we need only $1$ for each.

So we reduced the minimal number of distinct foci from $10$ to $4$. We can reduce this number further only if four or more people share at least one focus.

Four people $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ share at least one focus if there are edges $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$ and $CD$, that is if $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ form a quadrilateral together with diagonals.

No choice of four nodes represents a shared focus because there is no quadrilateral with diagonals in the graph. For example, in the quadrilateral $\{A,B,C,D\}$ both diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ are missing, so $A$ and $D$, and $B$ and $D$ don't participate in any shared activity.

Are there five or more people that share a focus? No, because if there were five (or more) people that shared one focus, than any four of those five (or more) would also share a focus, but we've just concluded that no four people share a focus.

Therefore, all the people in the triangles $ABE$, $ACE$, $BDF$ and $CDF$ share loci, together with all the people that form an edge. But since each edge is in one of these four triangles, we need at least $4$ loci.